# Can't make sure if my GPU works and having problems with high resolution videos

Tags: nvidia, gpu, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

I have lately installed ubuntu on my laptop, coming from windows. After some time online I realized that my laptop has problems with videos in 4k or 1440p. I searched online to find a way to see if my dedicated GPU was activated (since it needed to be done manually in windows) and if my integrated GPU couldn't take high resolution. After more research I became more confused, as I can see in my terminal that ubuntu recognizes both of them, but I don't know if it switches between them when needed. A proprietary driver means `vga.switcheroo` is disabled definitely, but `X.org X server` used in additional drivers also means I can't use the dedicated GPU(As far as I am aware). Running a 4k video even in the background gets all CPUs usage to about %60, running 3 videos brings all of them to %100, while still only the integrated one is being used. Also heard that nvidia is not well with linux OSes, does this mean I can only half-bakedly use my dedicated gpu, if at all?

Here are some screenshots:

[All the specs probably needed, above is the integrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAvpC.png)

[CPU usage while 4k videos are run, on the right it shows integrated is still in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbyH7.png)

[The same CPU usage seconds after windows are closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsTNV.png)

Sorry for my ignorance and possibly incorrect information within the question. I may have misexpressed some of the problems, I am fairly new to linux and never had to deal with this stuff before. Is there a way for me to just enable `vga.switcheroo` on linux with nvidia? Or is my problem with videos unrelated?

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit the Win-key, "Super-key" in Linux lingo, then type "software"... at least two icons will appear, click on the one saying "Software & Updates"
2. You should see "Ubuntu Software" as a tab-heading. Under it you will have possible tick marks for software categories; I'd say - enable all but "source code"
3. Switch to the "Additional Drivers" tab.
4. See if you have a suitable driver selection for your GPU available and ...
5. Make sure to select one of them.

*NOTE: It might be the case that the highest numbered one doesn't "work" for your hardware. Then check if choosing any one of the others helps.*

Comment: Thanks for the info. I went through nvidia's site to determine the necesarry driver for my OS and gpu, it is Linux X64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver with version 525, which is the highest number. If I just apply that, will it enable the dedicated gpu and also disable the vga? I am so cautious because I am worried I will screw sometihng up.

Comment: I tried this, used the recommended driver. Still has the same problem

Comment: 1. You may need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI. 2. If correctly installed, the Nvidia driver will also provide the Nvidia X Server Settings. Search it as you do with any program, open it, go to Profiles and select High Performance (Nvidia) and reboot to make sure you're using the discrete graphics.

Comment: Note: `lspci`, `lshw`, `lsusb` displays info on hardware that is present in the machine, I believe you have to look elsewhere for the "in active use" and "performance level" facts. Try: `$ nvidia-smi`. Also note that the latest version **does not necessarily** add **anything** to your hardware.